# Why entering OnCreate() when turning off mobile?

Tags: java, android, api, android-activity

I program my first Android app and am very new to Android development (as well as Java). I have PreferenceActivity and noticed that when activity is shown and I turn off mobile its onCreate() is called once again. Even more confusing is that static member `MyFirstAppActivity.camera` is not existing anymore causing exceptions. I can put check for null in there but I wonder why is this happening and whats the best way to avoid it?

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     // Root
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        // get list of available resolutions

        Object[] previewSizes = MyFirstAppActivity.camera.getParameters()
                .getSupportedPreviewSizes().toArray();

        // split object properties into two arrays

        String[] ps=new String[previewSizes.length];

        for(int i=0;i<previewSizes.length;i++)
        {
            try
            {
                int width=((Size)previewSizes[i]).width;
                int height=((Size)previewSizes[i]).height;
                ps[i]=width+"x"+height;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {}
        }

        // get list of available resolutions

        Object[] recordingSizes = MyFirstAppActivity.camera.getParameters()
                .getSupportedPictureSizes().toArray();

        // split object properties into two arrays

        String[] rs=new String[recordingSizes.length];

        for(int i=0;i<recordingSizes.length;i++)
        {
            try
            {
                int width=((Size)recordingSizes[i]).width;
                int height=((Size)recordingSizes[i]).height;
                rs[i]=width+"x"+height;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {}
        }

        Preference prefPreviewSizes = getPreferenceManager().findPreference("previewSizes");
        Preference prefRecordingSizes = getPreferenceManager().findPreference("recordingSizes");

        ((ListPreference) prefPreviewSizes).setEntries(ps);
        ((ListPreference) prefRecordingSizes).setEntries(rs);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever some sort of state change happens (for example, turning off or rotating the screen) the `onCreate` method gets called.

I'm pretty sure what you're supposed to do is override the  [`onSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) method and save data to it's `outState` Bundle, which then gets passed to `onCreate` as the `savedInstanceState` Bundle.

For some more info, check out "[Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)" in the Android developer center.

You might be able to keep your camera from causing exceptions by checking if it exists before creating it, something like

```
if(MyFirstAppActivity.camera == null)
    MyFirstAppActivity.camera = new Camera(...);
```

or just create a new instance of it in `onCreate`

Comment: Checking for null and assigning new Camera solved my problem, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check [Android's lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) information.

To make things a little better, you should implement `onPause` and `onResume`, as they are going to be called each time you change of Activity or rotate your phone. I assume that by turning off your mobile, you mean locking it and not powering it off. In that case, that `onCreate` may be called because your phone is cleaning the Activity stack to save battery.

In any case, you should add all the event listeners into the `onCreate` method, but anything related to the information being shown could go into `onResume` (and you should save any information or state during `onPause`). This way, your interface always shows fresh data each time your application state changes. (EditText and any standard widget stores by default its current state, but anything different from that should be carefully taken in consideration). You could place that camera inside that.

PS: I'm not sure this helps, but you may want to put that `camera` variable inside another class, probably a [Singleton](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton#Java). Storing information related to more than one Activity in an Activity may look strange in Android environments. Using a Singleton, you ensure your `camera` will be always accessible, wherever you call it (you'll still need to initialize it for the first time). You could also extend a basic activity holding a reference to camera, so any activity in need of this variable would have direct access to it (however, this increases the application's processing a little bit). I repeat this: this are just some advices on how I'd face this variable, they don't necessarily help you solving your problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The reason for having camera as static variable is because I had problems in passing it from activity to activity as normal object. Static seemed as easiest solution. Now, could you explain though why this static variable is returning null? I'm sure there is simple explanation that will embarass me horribly but I would love to know.

Comment: Well, it's just a supposition (I've never seen this situation), but bear in mind applications keep being paused and resumed, created and destroyed lots of times during its execution. It could be that your application lost track of when the camera was first created (probably inside `MyFirstAppActivity`), so your best chance here is to ensure you have your camera ready by checking it before (just like @TranquilMarmot suggested). Those lines are worth the exception you avoid.